Adding a list of graphs
In my report I need

list of table
List of figure
List of graphs

but a list of graphs does not exist in regular latex.
How can define list of graphs for my document?

Welcome. // I suggest you read a book on Latex, first. E.g. this online book answers all your 3 questions, see the Contents: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX

The tocloft package lets you define new "Lists of ...".  Have a look at section 2.4 of the user guide on CTAN.

You can use also the package float to make non standard floats.


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for  dummy text
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} % optional
\newfloat{graph}{tbp}{grp}
\floatname{graph}{Graph}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{graph} 
\centering (your plot) \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{graph}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\begin{graph}[h]
\centering (Another plot) \caption{Another  float for a graph.}
\end{graph}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\listof{graph}{List of Graphs}
\end{document}


Thankyou so much
